# Single Sign On-- SSO

Tags: dotnetopenauth, single-sign-on

Please I would like someone to tell me if dotNetOpenAuth single-sign-on.

All I want to achieve is to be able to seamlessly logging to all domains without redirect to third party system for authorisation or Authentication within a mixture programming platforms e.g (PHP or .Net)

Comment: Please I want to know if can Implement single-sign-on platform suing dotNetOpenAuth. 

All I want to achieve with single-sign-on is to be able to seamlessly logging to all domains without redirect to third party system for authorisation or Authentication within a mixture programming platforms e.g (PHP or .Net)

Answer (score 2):

DotNetOpenAuth library is a simple library to implement Single Sign On for .NET based application. The only issue I faced was related to performance. It was found to be a known issue with a particular API that cause the sluggishnes.

Comment: Please do not include a 'signature' in your posts; that is already done for you. Further, absolutely do not include non-related links to your website, as your posts will appear to be spam. I have edited the signature and link out of this post. Please keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

DotNetOpenAuth can be used for SSO solutions, but each new web site a user visits does need to perform a redirect to the identity provider.  In a controlled SSO environment, that provider may never appear to the user, so the login is totally transparent.  There are a couple of samples of an SSO configuration that comes with the DotNetOpenAuth download.

Answer (score 1):

DotNetOpenAuth will help you do what you want to do provided you can support OpenID from PHP. You need to implement a provider (the site that authenticates you against a DB or other store), and a consumer (the site you want to log into).

My recommendation would be to consider the authentication protocol you wish to use rather than a specific library at first. In the case if DotNet OpenAuth it has support for:

- [OpenID](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/about/about-openid/)
- [OAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/about/about-oauth/)
- [InfoCard](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/about/icard-overview/)

These are just a few of the protocols available. You should also look into the [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) family of protocols, in particular SAML 2.0.

There are implementations of SAML for PHP, .NET, and many other platforms. You might want to look at a [comparison between OpenID and SAML](http://identitymeme.org/doc/draft-hodges-saml-openid-compare.html) in order to choose which is better for you.